# Searching backwards with Boyer-Moore-Horspool

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, search, pattern-matching

I've implemented the Boyer-Moore-Horspool search algorithm, and it works great when I want to search forward in my text. I'm trying to adapt it to work backwards, and can't seem to get it right.

Is there an example of searching backwards using BMH?

As a reference, here's my code:

```
POSITION_T cDocument::FindNext(std::string needle, POSITION_T start)
{
    size_t buffersize = mBuffer.GetByteSize() ;
    size_t needlesize = needle.length() ;
    vector<int> badchars(256, -1) ;

    BadCharHueristic(needle, badchars) ;

    size_t s = mBuffer.ConvertPositionToByte(start) ;
    while(s <= (buffersize - needlesize))
    {
        ssize_t j = needlesize - 1 ;

        while(j >= 0 && needle[j] == mBuffer.GetByte(s + j))
        {
            j-- ;
        }

        if(j < 0)
        {
            // s holds our position in bytes
            return mBuffer.ConvertByteToPosition(s) ;
        }
        else
        {
            ssize_t b = j - badchars[mBuffer.GetByte(s + j)] ;
            s += Max(1, b) ;
        }
    }

    return GetTextSize() ;
}
```

Comment: reverse string and search forward?

Comment: The string is 500K, and could get bigger. My tests create a string of 2M. I'm thinking I could brute force a search in that time, especially if the user looks for the next match, also backwards, etc.

Comment: My suggestion is to copy and paste your working forward-searching code, and replace every array access expression that refers to the string `s[X]` with `s[len - X - 1]`, where `len` is (a variable containing) the string length.

Comment: Another way to accomplish the same idea (which might require more or less typing, depending on how many `std::string` operations you have to implement) is to make a copy of the function that accepts a `MyReversedString` instead of a `std::string` (or better yet, just make your existing function a template).  Probably all you need to implement is constructors and `MyReversedString& operator[](size_t i)`, which simply returns `s[len - i - 1]`.  BTW, pass your `string` by (const) reference instead of by value as you are currently -- the copying is wasteful, especially for long strings.

Comment: Using s[len - i - 1] works, until you start searching backwards from the middle of the text.

Comment: I may just go with KMP. Not as efficient, but that one I can do backwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Java Solution

public static int findLastBoore(char[] text, char[] pattern) {

    int n = text.length;
    int m = pattern.length;

    if (m == 0) return 0;
    Map<Character, Integer> last = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        last.put(text[i], -1);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++){
        last.put(pattern[k], k);
    }   
    int i = n - m;
    int k = 0;

    while (i > 0) {
        if (text[i] == pattern[k]) {
            if (k == m - 1) return i;
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            // Step backwards when there is a mismatch
            i-= m - Math.max(k + 1, last.get(text[i]));
            k = 0;
        }
        
    }
    return -1;
}
```

`